# Getting Error 415: SRVE0295E when using Scala Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, http, request, http-headers, akka

I am using Scala Akka HTTP to make an API call that requires a custom Content-Type (e.g. application/vnd+company.category+json).  The API I am trying to use requires this content type in the header.  Per Akka HTTP documentation, Content-Type can't be set explicitly into the headers of the HTTP request and must be set using the contentType property of the HttpEntity.  I'm not sure what Akka does to the contentType set in the HttpEntity, but it is obviously not appearing in the headers sequence of the HTTP message (as defined here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/common/http-model.html).  As a result, I consistently get Error 415: SRVE0295E, which translates to "415 Unsupported Media Type.  The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support."  I tried the API via curl with -H Content-Type of the same custom content type I have been using with Akka HTTP and I get a success response.  Has anyone ever run into a similar problem?

Comment: What I have:
`val customContentType =
    MediaType.applicationWithFixedCharset("vnd+company.category+json", HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`).toContentType
var request = RequestBuilding.Post(requestPath)
      .withHeadersAndEntity(headersList,HttpEntity(customContentType, ByteString(payload))`

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the API I am consuming has multiple variants of the custom Content-Type, each specific to the API endpoint to be consumed.  So this is not an Akka HTTP issue.